# I can't use extended attributes in gradle.kts

Tags: gradle-kotlin-dsl

## I created the gradle plugin using kotlin

### But I can't use extended attributes in app/build.gradle.kts

### I hope I can set the properties in build.gradle.kts and have them accessible in the plugin this is my code

```
class PluginTest : Plugin<Project> {

    override fun apply(project: Project) {

        project.extensions.create<BinaryRepositoryExtension>("app")

    }
}
```

## build.gradle.kts

```kotlin
apply{
    plugin<PluginTest>()
}
//this code i can use
idea is not hint
app{

}
```